# Exception specifications are not compatible in declaration and in realisation of function

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

We have following code

```
int main()
{
  void f() throw(int);
  f();
  return 0;
}

void f() { }
```

GCC and clang compiles it well. But, in standard there is such paragraph:

n3376 15.4/4

> If any **declaration of a function has an exception-specification** that is not a noexcept-specification allowing
> all exceptions, **all declarations, including the definition and any explicit specialization, of that function shall have a compatible exception-specification**.

And for following example: gcc - error, clang - warning

```
void f() throw(int);

int main()
{
  f();
  return 0;
}

void f() { }
```

Why there is difference in these snippets? Thanks.

Comment: Does a function that is declared inside another function even refer to the definition of a function of the same name outside? What does it mean to declare a function inside another one?

Comment: @jogojapan, can't find in standard nothing about this case. But anyway, there is no undefined reference here. http://liveworkspace.org/code/3BA8in$0 there is undef ref.

Comment: Yes, but the problem (even if it's a compiler problem) is related to that, not related to the handling of exception specifications. For example, if you declare `f` as returning `int` inside of `main`, but as returning `void` outside of `main`, it still compiles. Even if you call `f` and use its alleged return value. At least with g++ and clang: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2l5YiJ$1 Interestingly, the Intel compiler issues a warning.

Comment: @jogojapan, accepted. strange behaviour anyway, is something for this in gcc bugtracker? There is parameter -Wmissing-declarations, which will warn in such cases...

Comment: The closest I can find is this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28728 But that's only about the fact that you can declare functions inside other functions. It doesn't cover possible inconsistencies between declaration and definition.

Comment: Hmm... There is par 3.3.2/10 Function declarations at block scope
and variable declarations with the extern specifier at block scope refer to declarations that are members of
an enclosing namespace, but they do not introduce new names into that scope. I think it's related.

Comment: True. That seems to be it. Unfortunately only a _Note_, but still clearly an indication that the compilers are doing something wrongly as far as I understand.

Comment: It's strange, but where snippet is compiled with gcc/clang -x c command there is error. http://liveworkspace.org/code/2TEUYU$1

Comment: That looks like a bug. Clang is much worse, [it allows things](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7084) like `void f() { void g(); } string g() { }`.

Comment: @ForEveR that note is non-normative and defective. Each such block-scope declaration and also friend functions do introduce an invisible name into the enclosing namespace. Otherwise, ADL on those friend functions couldn't work at all. And otherwise, the rules at 3.3.1p4 wouldn't work at all (see the note for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The n3376 15.4/4 from the std specifie that all déclarations and definitions of a function must have the same throwing type. Here :

```
void f() throw(int);
int main()
{
  f();
  return 0;
}

void f() { }
```

the declaration `void f() throw(int);` and the definition `void f() { }` are in global scop. So they are in conflict because the declaration is for a function which throw int while the definition is for a function without a throw specification.

Now, when you put the declaration in the main scop, the definition isn't in the same scop, during this scop the definition isn't known so you can compile.

I hope you understood my english, sorry about it.

Comment: Not really true, but accepted. Actualy clang now handle this case, but only with warning: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/z6JcuiyJm7y87PXD